# Vue.js Condition: If contains

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I need to create condition in Vue for chcecking if array contains values.

```
items: { [1,5,8,12,63]}
                <div v-for="item in items">
                        <div v-if="item == 1">
                               Yes
                        </div>
                        <div v-else>
                            No
                        </div>
                </div>
```

And the output is: 
Yes, No, No, No, No .

I need to get only Yes and No one time.
I need:

Yes, No.

Comment: use array method i.e. `[].includes(item) ? true : false`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`v-for` will just loop through the array and `v-if`/`v-else` will conditionally render the appropriate block of code *for every item in the array*. What you should do instead is use a method to check if a number is in your `items` list. You can do that using `indexOf`..

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    items: [1, 5, 8, 12, 63]
  },
  methods: {
    itemsContains(n) {
      return this.items.indexOf(n) > -1
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div v-if="itemsContains(1)">
    Yes
  </div>
  <div v-else>
    No
  </div>
</div>
```

[See this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5om1vrt4/)

You can also get rid of the method and do your conditional inline if you want ..

```
<div id="app">
  <div v-if="items.indexOf(1) > -1">
    Yes
  </div>
  <div v-else>
    No
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    items: [1, 5, 8, 12, 63]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>

                

<div id="app">

  <div v-if="items.indexOf(1) > -1">
    Yes
  </div>
  <div v-else>
    No
  </div>
 
</div>
```